# how to convert hashtag in swift?

Tags: swift, textview, hashtag

I want to extract the hashtag.

```
func getHashtags() -> [String] {
    let words = components(separatedBy: " ")
    var hashTags = [String]()
    for word in words{
        if word.hasPrefix("#"){
            let hashtag = word.dropFirst()
            hashTags.append(String(hashtag))
        }
    }
    return hashTags
}
```

This method was not a good solution. "I want to eat #rice #eat." Hashtags are extracted well from sentences like

But if the sentence is like this,

[image]

Hashtags do not recognize line breaks, so the entire hashtag is not extracted. How can you solve this error? Tell me about the function that extracts the hashtag.

Comment: Please include sample data as text and not as images

Comment: I tried to extract hashtags from a multiline string with code similar to yours and it works fine so I guess the issue is related to your data more than your code.

Comment: sample data is this.
"hihihihii hashtag #hashtag #hi #asdf \n
#dfd
#dfsdfs"

Comment: You should edit the question and add that instead of posting it as a comment and also explain what result you get when running your code because to me it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can reformat your code for something like this. `string` here is your original text

```
func getHashtags() -> [String] {
     var words = string.components(separatedBy: "#") // Separate words by #
     var hashTags = [String]()
     // Check if the first word of sentence is a hashtag. If it is not then remove the first word
     // ex "firstWord #firstHashtag". Here "firstWord " should be removed
     var shouldRemoveFirstWord = !string.hasPrefix("#") 
     if shouldRemoveFirstWord {
         words.removeFirst()
     }
     
     for word in words{
         let trimmedWord = word.trim()
         // If the word has space then get only the first word
         let firstWord = word.components(separatedBy: " ")
         let hashtag = firstWord[0]
         hashTags.append(String(hashtag))
      }
      return hashTags
 }
```

And for the trim function, you can add it like this

```
    extension String {   
           func trim() -> String {
                return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
           }
    }
```

Comment: I was able to solve it by slightly modifying your code. Thank you